# Problems setting up a mail server in a EC2 instance

Tags: email, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to setup my own mail server in an EC2 instance on AWS. I've installed the following image:

https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B00K600RWK?ref=cns_srchrow

This image contains Webuzo: 2.2.9 + SquirrelMail:1.4.22. I followed all installation steps and the server is up and running ok. But whenever I try to login into an email account on SquirrelMail I get the following message:

```
"ERROR
Error connecting to IMAP server: ofaroldigital.com.br.
0 : php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No address associated with hostname"
```

Dig output:

```
$ dig ofaroldigital.com.br

; <<>> DiG 9.8.3-P1 <<>> ofaroldigital.com.br
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 9193
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;ofaroldigital.com.br.      IN  A

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
ofaroldigital.com.br.   173 IN  SOA ns-1959.awsdns-52.co.uk. awsdns-hostmaster.amazon.com. 1 7200 900 1209600 86400

;; Query time: 24 msec
;; SERVER: 212.58.251.198#53(212.58.251.198)
;; WHEN: Tue Feb  2 10:58:37 2016
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 125
```

I believe my route53 was configured correctly. What am I missing? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While ofaroldigital.com.br isn't resolving to anything, www.ofaroldigital.com.br is:

```
$ dig www.ofaroldigital.com.br +short
54.233.84.251
```

Have you made sure that you've added an A record for the Apex domain, that is to say, without the 'www' or any other subdomain?

Comment: I have 2 ec2 instances: for the website and another for the mail server. Please take a look on my route53 configuration: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/12985734/route53.png

Comment: That image shows there is no A record for "ofaroldigital.com.br", maybe you need to use the address "mail.ofaroldigital.com.br" to get to the imap server

Comment: So now I added a record for "ofaroldigital.com.br", and I still get no record on dig. But now it's a new issue with squirrelmail: "Error connecting to IMAP server: ofaroldigital.com.br.111 : Connection refused". Not sure why is pointing to the website not the mail server...

Comment: That means that ofaroldigital.com.br is resolving to something, but there's nothing running on port 111.

Comment: Fixed installing dovecot.